# How to get the name from firebase using spring

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, api

im new into using spring and firebase with Java and im trying to get the name of an user from my database on firebase to do a login that return the id of the name that the frontend sent me in a JSON file. The firebase scheme is
[firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TaTu.png)

my code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public String getName(@PathVariable String name) throws Exception {
        String name = "";
        List<PersonaDTO> list1 = personaServiceAPI.getAll();
        for(int i=0; i < list1.size(); i++){
            if(list1.get(i).getNombre().equals(nombre)){
                name = nombre;
                break;
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
```

this give me the error:

`"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Required URI template variable 'nombre' for method parameter type String is not present`

If anyone can give some tips or something i'll appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems here:

- The whole function make no sense. Why are you passing the user name and return the user name ? What's the purpose of this ?
- You should not combine english with other languages when writing code (ONLY ENGLISH)
- incorrect use of @PathVariable adnotation. You should have something like this :

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/login/{name}")
    public String getName(@PathVariable String name) throws Exception {...}
```

- unsuggestive variables name(ex: list1)
- declaring a local variable with the same name as the method argument
- performance issue: (fetching all the users from the database and then filter them by name insteam of querying directly the database and getting the exact user that you want).

My advice would be to edit the question and make it clearer for us and for you as well.